# error while trying to convert .py to .exe yolo8 application using pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, exe, yolo, yolov8

[SOLVED]
when i use Pyinstaller to convert my .py main file to .exe file, and run the exe file facing with a error that i dont have any idea about it. anybody can help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\data\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\data\base.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in <module>
  File "ultralytics\utils\__init__.py", line 234, in set_logging
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

i tried to edit main.spec file created by pyinstaller but it doent change anything

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
from ultralytics import YOLO
ultra_files = collect_data_files('ultralytics')

a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'], # <- Please change this into your python code name.
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=ultra_files, # <- This is for enabling the referencing of all data files in the Ultralytics library.
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    noarchive=False,
```

****UPDATE:**

so I turned on console in pyinstaller using `--console` arg and then opened `__init__.py` in ultralytics/utils
and in the line below:

```
DEFAULT_CFG_PATH = ROOT / 'cfg/default.yaml'
```

replace that with:

```
DEFAULT_CFG_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'default.yaml')
```

and place default.yaml (that is in ultralytics/cfg) in my main directory beside of main.py (and also main.exe)

then main.exe ran successfully but keep crashing when i wanted to predict some image, so in this case i add this to top of my main.py file and problem solved!:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

i hope this answer helps you.